# Project references C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, castle-windsor

I have a project (Project 1) that references another project (Project 2), and they are in two different solutions.

I recently changed Project 2's target framework from 3.5 to 4.5.

Project 1's target framework is 4.5.2.

Now I get issues with

> ConfigurationErrorsException: 'The type name  could not be located'

when I try to set up components with Castle.Windsor.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Making all projects the same net version?

Comment: But things worked fine before I changed Project 2's framework.. And yes, I have tried to make them the same version, but it doesn't work, so there must be something I'm missing

Comment: The reference might be broken. Try adding the reference again.

Comment: I have tried this as well.. and it doesn't seem broken. I get this error when I try to call a method that sets up an instance of a class with belonging pointers, such as references to classes in Project 2

Comment: Did you recompile Project 1? Make sure you clean the solution, then build again.

Comment: Yep, I have tried that as well

Comment: Making the projects the same version should have worked. I think it's possible Project 2 is not building. Check to see if the build process there is working.